# Angular 8 Login does not set cookies properly

Tags: angular, authentication, xmlhttprequest, jwt, angular-httpclient

This is a login system written in Angular 8 FrontEnd and Express.js (Node.js) BackEnd.

My goal is to login a user by POSTing to the `/api/login` the login details where login is checked and getting a response with a cookie set (in the format of key name `access_token` and content of `Bearer <jwt token here>`) for further authorization and also getting redirected to the dashboard. The `/api/login` responds with a `200` status code in case of a successful login with the mentioned cookie-set header (a.k.a new cookie) with `httpOnly:true` with the response.

My problem is that with the following code I get this error and I get no redirect and no cookie:

```
Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/api/login"
```

My code is the following:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/login`, { username, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (user && user.token) {

                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    // https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUserToken', JSON.stringify(user));
                    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                }
                console.log('User:', user);
                return user;
            }));
    }
```

P.S LocalStorage is deprecated and cookies are used for authentication and authorization.

---

If I add responseType: 'text' I get the following errors:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 15, '(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
  Overload 2 of 15, '(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "response"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
  Overload 3 of 15, '(url: string, body: any, options?: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
```

---

My backend code:

```
app.post('/api/login', apiLimiter, async function (req, res){
  // TODO: implement cookie check whether a still valid token is set and if so respond with cookie already set
  try  {
    let [sorted,users] = await getSorted();
    const pw = req.body.password;
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    console.log(await bcrypt.compare('testtest',hashedPassword));
    // const user = { id: req.body.id, username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password };
    var user = new User({firstname: req.body.firstname, eMail: req.body.eMail, password: hashedPassword });
    sorted.forEach(async ([firstname, password]) => {
      let result = bcrypt.compareSync(pw, password);
        // r = true if hash = hashed pw
        if (result === true) {
          jwt2.sign({user}, 'secrethere', { expiresIn: '15min'}, (err, token) =>{
            res.cookie(
              'access_token', 'Bearer '+ token, {
                expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), // cookie will be removed after 15 mins
                httpOnly: true
              })
            .send(200)
              .redirect(
                'http://localhost:4200/avior/dashboard'
              );
          });
          zehgreatresult = 1;
        } else{
          zehgreatresult = 0;
        }

    });    
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send()
    console.log(err);
  }
  if (zehgreatresult === 0){
    res.send("Wrong password!");
  }
});
```

---

My new code containing a redir which doesn't work for some reason:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/login`, { username, password }, {withCredentials: true})
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (user && user.token) {

                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    // https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUserToken', JSON.stringify(user));
                    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                }
                console.log('User:', user);
                this.redirtoDashboard();
                return user;

            }));
    }
 redirtoDashboard() {
      this.router.navigate(['http://localhost:4200/avior/dashboard']);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the response data you get from the back-end? Angular, by default, tries to parse as JSON the data received from the BE. It seems that this data is not formatted properly.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi in case of a successful auth it returns 200 which is just OK, in case of failed auth it returns the string "Wrong password!". Tried changing it to status code 401, it did not help

Comment: The issue is that you are sending a string and not at encoded JSON object. Try to encode the message "Wrong password!" into a JSON object and it should be work fine

Comment: @JacopoSciampi if I do that for some reason it only works if I click on submit and refresh the page. And by working I mean that the cookie is set, so that's only partial functionality.

Comment: Where do you have to code that allows you to do the redirect after the cookie is setted? I can only see a .next on a Subject/BehaviorSubject

Comment: @JacopoSciampi you're right. I tried implementing the redir, but it for some reason does not work. See the updated question please.

Comment: Edit the router navigation line this way: this.router.navigate(['avior/dashboard']); Also, can you please add to your quesiton your routing settings? I'm not totally sure about that route.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi by router settings you mean routing.ts?

Comment: Yes, the route configuration you've implemented in this project.

Comment: I already solved the problem, the problem was in the BackEnd, it wasn't delivering proper JSON.

Answer (score 0):

it should be a little bit other way of doing requests. you should use `withCredentials: true` as params to http methods like this

```
http.get(someUrl, {withCredentials: true});
http.post(someUrl, body, {withCredentials: true});
```

with this option it 1: will SET your cookies and 2: will attach your existing cookies to the request

Comment: Weird, it did not set the cookie and still throws the same error :/

Comment: could you check the response in the browser network tab?

Comment: but what is the content? I think i know the reason now

Comment: You mean what is being sent? `username` and `password` is being sent. The response is a cookie with key name `access_token` and value `Bearer <jwttokenhere>`

Comment: but what is the body of the response?

Comment: Just the word "OK". The express.js backend should redirect to a /dashboard url at this point

Comment: you are messing redirect ways of authorizing application with the ajax ones. It shouldn't work like that. You are now redirecting an AJAX request, not user. I'm not sure if it helps but you could try to skip parsing that useless response from your api `http.post(someUrl, body, {withCredentials: true, responseType: 'text'});`

Comment: I get errors, please check out the updated question

Comment: skip `any` typing and leave just nothing or `string` here `http.post--skip-here--(`

Comment: deleting `any` throws `Property 'token' does not exist on type 'string'.` and `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.`, adding String throws the same overload errors

Comment: that error comes from the handler. for the moment your API doesn't return you a user, so you won't  be able to handle it like that `.pipe(user => ...`. from what we've discussed the good way for you is to update your serve API to handle ajax authentication (it should indeed return User json in body rather than sending redirects to dashboard)

Comment: .send(200)
              .redirect(
                'http://localhost:4200/avior/dashboard'
              );
there is a redirect here, but your frontent needs a user. just do `.json(user)` instead

Comment: now in Postman it sends wrong password to me even though the password is ok -_- in Angular it seems to throw the same Http failure during parsing error

Comment: did you erased piece logic for some reason?

Comment: what is piece logic??

Answer (score 0):

By Default, the Http service is waiting for JSON Data, but your API is sending another form, simple text perhaps, so your have 2 solutions : 
 - Try to change your API code to send encoded JSON Data in PHP for example we use : json_encode funtion, in .Net JsonConvert.SerializeObject function ...
 - If you dont have access to your APi, try to force HTTP service to get text data by adding the folowing option :

```
this.http.post(
    `${environment.apiUrl}/api/login`,
    { username, password },
    {responseType: 'text'})
```

Comment: I use express.js for backend. I get the same errors as my new question was enchanced with